# Repair sprinkler pipe

Tags: plumbing, pvc, sprinkler-system, irrigation

What is the best way to repair a pvc T joint that connects two 1 inch pipes and has a threaded half inch T extension, which has been stripped? I can't attach the sprinkler head to it without it leaking.

I have included a picture below.

[image: sprinkler]

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Dig out the area enough to cut out the tee and enough pipe such that a new tee and a coupling can be glued in. This will result in slight re-positioning of the sprinkler.

If maintaining the position exactly is important, cut back enough pipe on both sides of the tee and use two couplings.

You will need to be able to pull up, flex, or move the pipe a bit to facilitate the installation of new fittings. If this is not feasible, I have had good luck with **repair couplings**, which open like a clam shell or come in two pieces; so you do not need any pipe flex:

[image]

Comment: P.S. - always debur your pipe, sand your pipe and fittings clean, and use purple primer. Also, glue the crap out of these repair couplings.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say debur the pipe? I'm familiar with sanding the pvc, priming and gluing.

Comment: Just meant use a strip of sandpaper to knock off the "hanging chad" left after cutting PVC. If you can't prevent it from entering the pipe, make sure you remove the furthest downstream sprinkler head, screw a long nipple and elbow in, and flush the system thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up taking the easy and slightly more expensive way out.

1. I started by cutting out the stripped T at the lines below.
   [image]
2. Then I slid on a [new 1/2" PVC-Lock FPT Tee](http://hydrorain.com/products/pvc_lock/1_2_inch_PVC_Lock_fittings)
3. Then I took a [1/2" PVC-Lock Slide Repair Fitting](http://hydrorain.com/products/pvc_lock/PVC_Lock_Slide_Repair_Fittings) and made an additional cut just big enough to attach the slide fitting (fully compressed to be as small as possible) to the tee.
4. Then I inserted the male end of the slide fitting into the female (non-threaded) end of the Tee fitting.
5. Then I expanded the slide repair fitting to meet the other end of the pipe.

The finished product looked like this (Please forgive the crude drawing. I am posting this after I buried it again).

[image]

The PVC Lock parts made it easier and I didn't have to buy/store PVC primer and glue. However this should only be used in cold water, outdoor low pressure irrigation systems.